# get the right dom element

Tags: jquery-selectors

i have the following htl markup

```
<iframe id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02_ctl00" frameborder="0" style="height:       100%; width: 100%; border-width: 0px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="ContentPlaceHolder1_Editor1_ctl02_ctl00">
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
     sa
    <br>
 </body>
</html> 
</iframe>
```

I need a way to chang the text in the body tag using jquery selector

thanks.

Comment: The html you what in your iframe needs to be in a different html file, and linked into the iframe with src attribute. Html directly inside the iframe tag is not supported

Answer (score 0):

This post might be helpful

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: thanks for your fast replay...your suggestion not seem to work with my case..i try it